# selenium tests got slow after upgrading framework to .NET6.0

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, nunit, winappdriver

selenium tests got slow after upgrading framework to .NET6.0
below is proj file

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>test</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>test</AssemblyName>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <AssemblyTitle>test</AssemblyTitle>
    <Product>test</Product>
    <Copyright>Copyright ©  2019</Copyright>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
 
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="test.runsettings">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DnsClient" Version="1.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="ExtentReports.signed" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" Version="3.2.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Bson" Version="2.7.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.7.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver.Core" Version="2.7.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.13.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="4.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="RazorEngine" Version="3.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Buffers" Version="4.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver" Version="85.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="3.141.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.141.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Buffers" Version="4.5.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Expecting tests to run faster.`your text`
I cannot upgrade Selenium.Support and webdriver to latest due to below issue

For now, WinAppDriver is not supported by Selenium 4 due WinAppDriver is not yet W3C compliant.  should install Selenium Pre 4.0 (e.g. version 3.4) for all Selenium libraries. Also, set up an appropriate appium nuget.

Downgrade (Selenium.WebDriver and Selenium.Support) nuget packages to 3.141.0....

Comment: What are you trying to do? .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6, not .NET Framework 4+2. WinAppDriver isn't a real Selenium WebDriver and hasn't been updated in 4 years. It'll never become W3C compliant not only because it's abandoned but because it just isn't meant for web testing. It was used for Selenium-*like* UI tests. There are better ways to do desktop UI tests

Comment: The packages you show are ancient too. `Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver` is at 114, not 85. You won't find any Chrome 85 installation anywhere because Chrome automatically updates itself. `System.Buffers"` is part of the runtime, and at version 6.0.

Comment: WinAppDriver was literally intended for *Desktop* apps, and their related frameworks like WinForms, WPF, etc. Not only should you be using the proper Core implementation of the Selenium library, but if this is not truly a desktop app then most likely your test suite should be rewritten to be using Selenium entirely and not the WinAppDriver